# How to operate an exercise in the tutorial without running the codes above in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to code a tutorial in Rmarkdown with shiny apps. It works well until I added an exercise on the page. When I clicked the "Run Code" button, it ran all the codes above and performing their real outcome instead of a display as in the screenshots. Also, the last code I write in the exercise is shown whenever I browse the tutorial.

Does anyone have this problem or a solution?

https://www.flickr.com/photos/149687914@N08/46862084412/in/dateposted-public/

https://www.flickr.com/photos/149687914@N08/31973148497/in/dateposted-public/

The chunks below the exercise chunk are normal as shown below:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/149687914@N08/31973612587/in/dateposted-public/

When I click the "Run Code" it actually runs all the code above on the page.

Full Code: https://codeshare.io/Gkx8Wx

Comment: Isn't it supposed to show the output once it's run?

Comment: Can you share what's the code above that produces output?

Comment: Yes, it is but without the exercise chunk, there weren't any check marks in front of the headers. And also, it was just displaying the code before. Now, it seems to run the code above the exercise chunk rather than to display. I added the SS of what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting the problem. You have got non-exercise chunk and those are not to be executed or your exercise chunk itself is getting auto-executed?

Comment: I added the code as Full Code: https://codeshare.io/Gkx8Wx

Comment: Did you check the answer if that's what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, I checked and thank you. I couldn't see the difference. I added a detailed comment below your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'm getting from this below code. This seems to be rendering properly, Can you please check that once?

````
---
title: "Hello, Tutorial!"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r}
library(rebmix)
library(learnr)
data("wine", package = "rebmix")
library(data.table)
wine <- as.data.table(wine)
str(wine)
```

### Exercise: Try for the wine Data

Subset rows where Cultivar value is 1, and then subset rows where Cultivar is 1
and Proline is greater than 1000. Then, subset the rows between 10 and 30.

```{r datatable, exercise=TRUE, exercise.eval=FALSE}

```


```{r datatable-solution}

wine1 <- wine[Cultivar == 1 & Proline > 1000]
wine2 <- wine[10:30]

```

```{r datatable-hint-1}

wine1 <- wine[Cultivar == 1, ...]

```
```{r datatable-hint-2}

wine1 <- wine[Cultivar == 1 & Proline > 1000]

```
```{r datatable-hint-3}

wine2 <- wine[10:?]

```
````

This the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works fine even when I added the other details to script. I changed the first chunk as 'setup' - include = FALSE, and added another chunk as '''{r} head(wine) '''  It works fine this time. However, when I run the code in my original script, it runs as before.

With your template it is like this:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/149687914@N08/46000717495/in/dateposted-public/

With mine:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/149687914@N08/39950286083/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: In my code, as you can see, it changes the display completely. It was like yours before I added the exercise chunk. Can it be related to caches?

Comment: @BatuhanKavlak Not sure or it could be because of the library `learnr` loading. Not sure really.